# How can I prove that $F_1(x)=\frac{x^2+2}{3}$ can be used to solve $f(x)=x^2-3x+2=0$ with the fixed point method?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Let we have the following equation: $f(x)=x^2-3x+2=0$

How can I **prove** that $F_1(x)=\frac{x^2+2}{3}$ can be used to solve that equation with the fixed point method?

---

I have calculate the roots of f(x) so I know that the solutions of the equation are $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$.

But how I make sure that $F_1(x)$ can be used for it using the fixed point method?

Comment: note if $F_1(x)=x$ then $x^2-3x+2=0$

Comment: $$x^2-3x+2=0\iff x=\frac{x^2+2}3$$

Comment: Is it enough to say that?

Comment: you should show it's a contraction mapping

Comment: I think no, you have to somehow estimate $|x_{n+1}-a|$ in terms of $|x_n-a|$ where $a$ is the root to show the method converges ($x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+2}{3}$). @User160

Comment: What is that? Or how can I do that? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I don't understand what you've said @AlexeyBurdin

Comment: $F$ is a contraction mapping on a set $U$ if there is some $M < 1$ such that $|F(x) - F(y)| \le M|x - y|$ for all $x, y \in U$. From this, it follows that $|F^n(x) - F^n(y)| < M^n|x - y| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so $F^n(x)$ converges for all $x \in U$ and always to the same limit. Your $F_1$ is not a contraction everywhere, but it is a contraction on a certain interval.